# I am trying to calculate the subtotal of a set of functions but am getting no output:

Tags: javascript, html, css

My html looks like this:

```
    <tr>
      <td><input id="z1" type="number"  
      oninput="calculateSubTotal()">
      </td>
      <td>Shirts - WASH - Qty 1 to 4</td>
      <td>2.50 ea</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
```

and my js looks like this:

```
function calculateSubTotal() { 
 var subTotal = (getTableOnePrice() + getTableTwoPrice() + getTableThreePrice() + getTableFourPrice());
 document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML = subTotal.toFixed(2);
 return subTotal;
}
```

One of the functions looks like this:

```
function getTableTwoPrice(){    

var ba = document.getElementById("y1").value * 6.00;

var bb = document.getElementById("y2").value * 1.25;

var bc = document.getElementById("y3").value * 4.00;

var bd = document.getElementById("y4").value * 6.00;

var be = document.getElementById("y5").value * 7.00;

var bf = document.getElementById("y6").value * 8.00;

var bg = document.getElementById("y7").value * 9.00;

var bh = document.getElementById("y8").value * 5.00;

var bi = document.getElementById("y9").value * 13.00;

var bj = document.getElementById("y10").value * 10.00;

var bk = document.getElementById("y11").value * 12.00;

var bl = document.getElementById("y12").value * 14.00;

var bm = document.getElementById("y13").value * 16.00;

var bn = document.getElementById("y14").value * 10.00;

var tableTwoTotal = ba + bb + bc + bd + be + bf + bg + bh + bi + bj + bk + bl + bm + bn;

   return tableTwoTotal;
 }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This `document.getElementById("...").value * xyz.zyx` will return `0`.

Comment: May I ask why it would return 0? I am still relatively new to html and js so I am having a hard time grasping these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `onchage` event. I've seen that `oninput` doesn't work in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on getting something to write to the screen first. And yes onchange is what you want here as oninput changes for every keystroke.

```
<tr>
      <td><input id="z1" type="number" onchange="calculateSubTotal()">
      </td>
      <td>Shirts - WASH - Qty 1 to 4</td>
      <td>2.50 ea</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <div id='subtotal'></div>

 <script>   
    function calculateSubTotal() { 
    var subTotal = getTableOnePrice();
    document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML = subTotal.toFixed(2);
    return subTotal;
    }
    function getTableOnePrice(){
        return 5
    }
</script>
```

once you have something like that working you can add the real getTableOnePrice() and all the others back in.